# How to remove class from another element and add to another?

Tags: jquery

need your help! I want to show subcategory menu, based on the index of menu link, i pressed.

For now i come up with this code:

```
$( ".main-menu-link-container" ).click(function() {
  var index = $( ".main-menu-link-container" ).index( this );
  $ ( ".subcategory-menu-links-wrapper" ).eq(index).addClass ( "show" );
});
```

But now subcategory containers shows on top of each other. How can i remove class "show" from one div, and add to another, when i click another link? Thank you!

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: add more code, to see what's going to wrong

Comment: Better, create a minimal runnable example.

Comment: you can add jsfiddle/code snippet  , so easy understand error and easily solve

Comment: *But now subcategory containers shows on top of each other* - sounds there's more than just `$(x).addClass(c1); $(y).removeClass(c1)` (which is what you're asking).  Without seeing your css and html to determine exactly what is causing the issue, the question your asking is *just* `.addClass` and `.removeClass` - but that's not what you want to know, you should ask why it doesn't work in your scenario; and for that we need to see your scenario *in action*.  Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there should only be one element with the class `.show` you could select that class for the removement before adding that class to the new element:

```js
$('.show').removeClass('show');
```

Would look in your code like this:

```js
$( ".main-menu-link-container" ).click(function() {
  var index = $( ".main-menu-link-container" ).index( this );

  $( ".show" ).removeClass( "show" );
  $( ".subcategory-menu-links-wrapper" ).eq(index).addClass( "show" );
});
```